# How to execute multiple SQL about Spring batch JdbcItemWriter

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have to write data into multiple tables using Spring batch. For example, I have two tables: user table and information table.

I don't want to use stored procedure, but `JdbcItemwriter` does not allow executing multiple SQL. I want to execute multiple SQL in `JdbcItemWriter`.

I'm looking for pointers and general advice about the optimal way to perform this.

Comment: You should try showing what you've tried, or being more specific with what you're looking for.

Comment: I add a stepListener afterStep to excute another sql  when the  preparedStatementSetter set the first sql, but i hope the two sql insert operation is  parallel running

Answer (score 3):

I usually need to do multiple inserts for each element. For example, when reading from a file (like a structured XML).
To do that, I usually implement a specific `ItemWriter` class where the properties are the specific `JdbcItemWriter` classes for each of my tables. Here's an example:

```
package my.package.writer;

import  my.package.model.tbl.MyMainObject;
import  my.package.model.tbl.MySubObject1;
import  my.package.model.tbl.MySubObject2;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class MainMultipleWriter implements ItemWriter<PkjwdPolizze>
{

    private CounterBean                    counterBean;
    private ItemWriter<MyMainObject>       writerMyMainObject;
    private ItemWriter<MySubObject1>       writerSubObject1;
    private ItemWriter<MySubObject2>       writerSubObject2;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void write(List<? extends MyMainObject> items) throws Exception
    {
        // Main Table WRITER
        writerMyMainObject.write(items);

        // Secondary Table WRITERS
        for (MyMainObject item : items)
        {
            writerSubObject1.write(item.getLstMySubObject1());
            writerSubObject2.write(item.getLstMySubObject2());              
        }
    }
}
```

After this you configure your job to use your `MultiWriter` class instead of a simple `JdbcItemWriter`. Here's an example of that configuration:

```
<!-- job -->
<batch:job id="myJob" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="myStep" >
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk commit-interval="2500" reader="myReader"
                processor="myProcessor" writer="myMultiWriterBean" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- Writers -->
<bean id="myMainObjectWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="my.package.setters.MyMainObjectStatementSetter"></bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sql" value="--insert_statement--" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySubObject1Writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="my.package.setters.MySubObject1StatementSetter"></bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sql" value="--insert_statement--" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySubObject2Writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="my.package.setters.MySubObject2StatementSetter"></bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sql" value="--insert_statement--" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="myMultiWriterBean" class="my.package.writer.MainMultipleWriter">
    <property name="writerMyMainObject" ref="mySubObject1Writer" />
    <property name="writerSubObject1" ref="mySubObject2Writer" />
    <property name="writerSubObject2" ref="mySubObject2Writer" />
</bean>
```

I think this is a cleaner implementation, because you respect the chunk structure and don't have to worry about rollback, transaction and data integrity.

Comment: Thanks nice example.Do you have any repository where I can refer the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [CompositeItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) with two `JdbcItemWriter` delegates.

Comment: Not working with a transaction. If one JdbcItemWriter throw an exception in a chunk. He will retry whole CompositeItemWriter but some JdbcItemWriter can be already commited...(JdbcItemWriter auto commit)

Comment: JdbcItemWriter does not auto commit? each chunk runs in it's own transaction.

Answer (score 0):

check out the `CompositeItemWriter` configuration example as follows:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourBeanDto> jdbcUpdateTable1Writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourBeanDto> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setAssertUpdates(true);
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql(" Update .... ");
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<YourBeanDto>());
    return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourBeanDto> jdbcInsertTable2Writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourBeanDto> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql(" Insert .... ");
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<YourBeanDto>());
    return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public CompositeItemWriter<YourBeanDto> compositeItemWriter(
    @Qualifier("jdbcUpdateTable1Writer") JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourBeanDto> jdbcUpdateTable1Writer,
    @Qualifier("jdbcInsertTable2Writer") JdbcBatchItemWriter<YourBeanDto> jdbcInsertTable2Writer) {
    CompositeItemWriter<YourBeanDto> writer = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
    writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(jdbcUpdateTable1Writer, jdbcInsertTable2Writer));
    return writer;
}
```